# Dockerfile run python command not working

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
ADD reports /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
RUN ls -l /code/reports/report/manage.py  # gives expected result
RUN ls -l /code/reports/build_static/  # gives expected result
RUN python /code/reports/report/manage.py build full_report.views.RenderView  # does not work
```

Everything works fine except for the **last command** which runs a python package (django-bakery) through `manage.py build`. I don't get any errors.

This command should output some files inside build_static directory in the container.

**If I ssh into the container and run the command manually then it is working**. I inserted the full path with `/code/` to make sure that they match and created all necessary directories beforehand.

This is how I build the container:

```
docker-compose run django /bin/bash
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  django:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I wonder how come it is working when I run the command manually through bash inside the container, but not working with the command in the dockerfile.

Thanks!

Update (it seems that the files are created, but then if I check on them they aren't there):

```
Step 12/12 : RUN ls -l /code/reports/build_static/
 ---> Running in e294563d26d5
total 11080
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11339956 Apr 30 10:53 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root     4096 Apr 30 10:53 static
Removing intermediate container e294563d26d5
 ---> b8e72da8ee5c
Successfully built b8e72da8ee5c
Successfully tagged image_django:latest
WARNING: Image for service django was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
root@7483853ecc45:/code# ls -l reports/build_static/
total 0
```

Comment: What command you are using to ssh into the container ?

Comment: @fly2matrix it does it automatically after creating the container. otherwise I use `docker exec -it id bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following steps and let me know output:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
ADD reports /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
RUN ls -l /code/reports/report/manage.py  # gives expected result
RUN ls -l /code/reports/build_static/  # gives expected result
RUN python /code/reports/report/manage.py build full_report.views.RenderView  
RUN ls -l /code/reports/build_static/  # should give you expected list of files
```

Give me output for the last step.
I'll help you out based on output.

Comment: yes, that one gives me the right output. but then there is nothing in there if I run the command manually after I ssh in the container. I updated the question with the result

Comment: Is it something related to the volumes? the fact that I have a build_static folder already which is empty? If so, what can one do?

Comment: I removed `volumes: - .:/code` from docker-compose.yml and now it stays there. So I think that was it. Thank you so much, you directed me to the right solution.

Comment: Actually YES : It is an issue with volume... Try removing that part from docker-compose.yml and you will see all your files.

Answer (score 1):

The following Dockerfile, copies your current directory content to a `code` folder (if it doesn't exist, it creates it), then sets it as the workdir.

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD,
>   ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile

Then, in order to reduce you docker image size to the maximum, we regroup all your commands in one `RUN` command so that it reduces the number of layers.

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    ls -l reports/report/manage.py && \
    ls -l reports/build_static/ && \
    python reports/report/manage.py build full_report.views.RenderView
```

I haven't tried it with a full Django app example, but it should help you narrow down the problem !